# How to output progress of parallel process on regular basis?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm learning python multiprocessing module and I've found [this](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html) example (this is a bit modified version):

```
#!/bin/env python
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import string
import time

# Define an output queue
output = mp.Queue()

# define a example function
def rand_string(length, output):
    time.sleep(1)
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(
                    string.ascii_lowercase
                    + string.ascii_uppercase
                    + string.digits)
               for i in range(length))
    result = (len(rand_str), rand_str)
    # print result
    time.sleep(1)
    output.put(result)


def queue_size(queue):
    size = int(queue.qsize())
    print size


# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
processes = [mp.Process(target=rand_string, args=(3, output)) for x in range(1,1000)]


# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()


# Get process results from the output queue
# results = [output.get() for p in processes]
# print(results)
```

I want to add some progress-bar to this code. I do not know which is the best way to do it. Here is my 1st approach which basically runs in infinite loop at parent process and counts the elements in queue:

```
#!/bin/env python
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import string
import time

# Define an output queue
output = mp.Queue()

# define a example function
def rand_string(length, output):
    time.sleep(1)
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(
                    string.ascii_lowercase
                    + string.ascii_uppercase
                    + string.digits)
               for i in range(length))
    result = (len(rand_str), rand_str)
    # print result
    time.sleep(1)
    output.put(result)


def queue_size(queue):
    size = int(queue.qsize())
    print size


# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
processes = [mp.Process(target=rand_string, args=(3, output)) for x in range(1,1000)]


# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

# max_size 
while True:
  current_size = output.qsize()
  max_size     = len(processes)
  print "%s %%" % (current_size*100/float(max_size))
  if current_size == max_size:
    break
  time.sleep(0.5)


# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()

# Get process results from the output queue
# results = [output.get() for p in processes]
# print(results)
```

The output of this is following:

```
71.3713713714 %
79.8798798799 %
86.8868868869 %
93.3933933934 %
99.7997997998 %
100.0 %
```

My 2nd approach was to create an an separate process which will handle progress counting (basically the same way as 1st approach, by counting the elements in qeue):

```
#!/bin/env python
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import string
import time

# Define an output queue
output = mp.Queue()

# define a example function
def rand_string(length, output):
    time.sleep(1)
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(
                    string.ascii_lowercase
                    + string.ascii_uppercase
                    + string.digits)
               for i in range(length))
    result = (len(rand_str), rand_str)
    # print result
    time.sleep(1)
    output.put(result)


def count_progress(queue, max_size):
    current_size = queue.qsize()
    if current_size <= max_size:
    # while current_size <= max_size:
        print "%s %%" % (current_size*100/float(max_size))
        # time.sleep(1)


# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
processes = [mp.Process(target=rand_string, args=(3, output)) for x in range(1,1000)]


# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

p_progress_count = mp.Process(target=count_progress, args=(output, len(processes)))
p_progress_count.start()
p_progress_count.join()

# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()


# Get process results from the output queue
# results = [output.get() for p in processes]
# print(results)
```

The output of this is following:

```
69.5695695696 %
```

Questions:

1. As you can see both progress outputs looks ugly (too few outputs). Is it possible to print out progress on regular basis, e.g. every second?
2. Is there any way that I can prefer running one process over another (run more often `count_progress` over `rand_string`) than other process? I think it would be possible by adding sleep to the end of `rand_string`, but it seems like performance waste to me.
3. What is the best way of handling similar problems?
4. Is writing/reading to/from `output` what is knowns as inter process communication using shared memory?

Answer (score 0):

By sub-classing `multiprocessing.Process` the progress counter you can get the progress whenever you want. Also there is an added `Pipe` and `Queue` to receive progress from the other working processes. There is some added complication but the progress is more reliable than checking for queue size.
Also starting a large number (1000) of `rand_string`-like processes may not be advisable. Instead just make one process that produces the 'random strings'.
I have written some sample code showing how to sub-class the `Process` class to make the `progress_counter`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import string
import time



# define a example function
def rand_string(length, output , progress_sender):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(
                    string.ascii_lowercase
                    + string.ascii_uppercase
                    + string.digits)
               for i in range(length))
    result = (len(rand_str), rand_str)
    # print result
    output.put(result)
    progress_sender.send(1)

#sub classed progress counter
class count_progress(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe_recv, max_size,progress_queue):
        super(count_progress, self).__init__()
        self.current_size = 0
        self.progress = 0
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.pipe_recv = pipe_recv.recv
        self.progress_queue = progress_queue
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.current_size +=self.pipe_recv()
            self.progress = (self.current_size *100/float(self.max_size))
            self.put_progress()
            # if int(self.progress)%10==0:
            #     print self.progress
            if self.progress>=100:
                break
        return

    def put_progress(self):
        if  not self.progress_queue.empty():
            self.progress_queue.get()
        self.progress_queue.put(self.progress)


if __name__=='__main__':
    # Define an output queue
    output = mp.Queue()
    progress_queue = mp.Queue(1)  # queue to poll for progress
    recv, sendr = mp.Pipe() # pipe for example function to send progress

    # Setup a list of processes that we want to run
    processes = [mp.Process(target=rand_string, args=(3, output, sendr)) for x in range(1,20)]

    # p_progress_count = mp.Process(target=count_progress, args=(recv, len(processes)))
    p_progress_count = count_progress(recv, len(processes), progress_queue)
    p_progress_count.start()
    # Run processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    # poll for the progress any time you want
    while p_progress_count.is_alive():
        print 'progress at %.2f%%' % progress_queue.get()
        time.sleep(1)
    print 'progress at %d%%' % 100
    p_progress_count.join()

    # Exit the completed processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # Get process results from the output queue
    # results = [output.get() for p in processes]
    # print(results)
```